# REACT: pushing an item to an array inside the state

Tags: reactjs, state

YES I know this is a common question, however **I can not seem to get provided examples to work in my situation...**
I have an empty array in my state:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                selectedItems: []
             }
         }
```

And I want to simply add items to that array with this code (it's in a function):

```
this.setState( {
    selectedItems:[...this.state.selectedItems, data]
  })
```

data in this case being the thing added to the state array.

The problem I encounter(**when I console.log this.state**) is that the first occurrence of this push to the array never works. `SO` for example, if I pushed to it 4 different times, only three will be in the state array and it will not register the first time I tried.

I am lost as to why. Any help appreciate. =)

Comment: Where do you `console.log(this.state)`?

Comment: Just directly below, after the this.setState() call in the same function

Comment: try this `this.setState( {
    selectedItems:[...this.state.selectedItems, data]
  }, () => console.log(this.state))`. Setting state is asynchronous in React, so it happens after some time.. you need to do a callback as second argument, to know the new state

Comment: Are you trying to console.log after the setState? If so add the console.log in a function as the 2nd argument of setState.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactjs setState asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029244/reactjs-setstate-asynchronous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.setState( { selectedItems:[...this.state.selectedItems, data] }, () => console.log(this.state))
```

Try this with the log as the 2nd argument of setState, this will run once the state has been updated

Comment: Yes thank you very much, I seemed to have been using the console log in the wrong location as you said

Answer (score 1):

If you're logging the state directly after setting it, it will be updated asynchronously. To get the final value you can use `setState` callback:

```
this.setState({
  selectedItems: [...this.state.selectedItems, data]
}, () => console.log(this.state))
```