# Getting current user's data from firebase firestore in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from firestore, but I can't seem to do it properly and it always returns null. Here's what I tried:

```
Map<String, dynamic>? userMap2;

void getCurrentUser() async {
FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
final uuid = user!.uid;

setState(() {
  isLoading = true;
});

await _firestore
    .collection('users')
    .where("uid", isEqualTo: uuid)
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  setState(() {
    userMap2 = value.docs[0].data();
    isLoading = false;
  });
  print(userMap2);
});
```

}

and when I try to use that data, I try to use it like this: `userMap2!['firstName']`

Comment: what is the value of `uuid`? print(uuid)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put user data in document and then use,

```
     _firestore
     .collection('users')
     .doc(uuid)
     .get().then((value) {
      setState(() {
      userMap2 = value.docs[0].data();
      isLoading = false;
  });
   print(userMap2);
 });
```

Comment: It gave me an error like this: "error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'. (undefined_getter at [sportal] lib\screens\messageSearch_s.dart:71)"

Answer (score 0):

In React, calling `setState` is an asynchronous operation. In addition, loading data from Firestore is an asynchronous operation. This means that in your current code, the `print(userMap2)` runs before your `then` callback is called, and even further before the `userMap2 = value.docs[0].data()` has been completed.

I recommend not combining `then` with `await`, and doing:

```
const value = await _firestore // 
    .collection('users')
    .where("uid", isEqualTo: uuid)
    .get();
setState(() {
  userMap2 = value.docs[0].data();
  isLoading = false;
});
print(value.docs[0].data()); //
```

On the first line I marked, we're now taking the return value from the `await`ed `get()`, so that we no longer need a `then` block. This handles the asynchronous nature of the call to Firestore.

Then on the second marked line, we print the value directly from the results from the database, instead of from the `setState` call. This addresses the asynchronous nature of calling `setState`.

For more on these, see:

- [Why is setState in reactjs Async instead of Sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)
- [Reactjs setState asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029244/reactjs-setstate-asynchronous) (which shows how to pass a second argument to `setState` that is run when the state has been set).